# Cocoa: how to reference lots of NSSliders

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsslider

I have this xib file for my main window, and it contains 64 sliders to be able to create a matrix mix for an audio application.
Setting the values using the sliders works, but I also want to save the values to the default preferences and load them back in the next time the application is started.
I have this working, but the sliders are not representing the actual values when the preferences are loaded.

How would i do this, without having to create 64 `IBOutlets` in my app controller?
I have the actual values in a `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: I would do such many UI elements in code rather than in IB.

Comment: @dasdom so, what would be the easiest way to add, show and position those elements in a grid-like fashion? Do I need to do something with cells? I'm fairly new to cocoa programming (as you can probably tell...)

Comment: Sorry, I am iOS developer. Table views are very different there. You could position them in a for loop and using tags you can identify them. But I assume you have already thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an [outlet collection](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/3/28/interface-builder-outlet-collections.html) will help you?

Comment: you made me very happy at first, seemed like exactly what i needed, however, it doesn't seem to be available in OSX? I Guess i forgot to mention i'm not targeting iOS...